# How do I get a live USB install without the install prompt?

Tags: boot, live-usb, iso, live-cd

I have a Ventoy drive with a handful of ISOs for testing purposes. Since it's for testing and troubleshooting systems, it's useful for reaching the desktop to be quick. For my use case, the prompt to either install or try Ubuntu is unnecessary. I've looked online a bit, but all answers are for older versions or just say to click 'try'.

If anyone knows how to do what I'd like with Ubuntu 21, I'd appreciate your advice. If it's just not easily possible, I'd appreciate flavour recommendations where it is possible.

Edit: it's preferable that it's accessible straight from the ISO, as that's a requirement for a Ventoy multi boot drive.

Comment: You¡d have to re-encode the installer and it's as far from easy as it gets indeed and flavors are the same in that regard.

Comment: Open the USB installer. Open /boot/grub/grub.cfg and remove `maybe-ubiquity` from the first menuentry, save. Best to use Rufus or mkusb for making the boot USB. so that the USB is editable. This should work with Ubuntu 21.10. Previous versions may use txt.cfg to boot in BIOS mode, it can be edited similarly.

Comment: @user68186 It directed me to what I think are the right files... but if possible, I'd like to have this accessible straight from the ISO, and that doesn't work as far as my tests...

Comment: @3XC4L1B3R Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I agree that the "How to bypass ..." question that was linked as a duplicate is not quite what you are asking for. That was about modifying a Live USB. However, you are using Ventoy USB and are asking how to modifying the *ISO* that lives on the USB to bypass the "install" screen. As ChanganAuto mentioned, this won't be easy, but see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156045/1165986) for a solution that is reported to work in recent Ubuntu versions (along with the "bypass" question/answer, of course).  Let me know if that's not it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for your help, I managed to do it with [Cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic). The bypass question wasn't so helpful, but thanks to a [question](https://answers.launchpad.net/cubic/+question/683108) on the Cubic site, I learned that the 'try' prompt is just a package standard in Ubuntu ISOs, so all I had to do was remove it with Cubic. Thanks!

Comment: @3XC4L1B3R Excellent - Good to hear!